# Full system export failed: Job org.artifactory.repo.service.ExportJob cannot stop related job artifactory.ExportJob

Tags: backup, artifactory

I have inherited an Artifactory 6.16 system(with a basic license which points to this forum for community support) and have very little knowledge and experience on how it works(this will probably change in the future). I do have plenty of Linux experience though. I am tasked with creating a full backup of the system with the intention of wiping out the artifacts and rebuilding it later. I plan to take two approaches to this:

1. Copy the raw repository data along with the MySQL DB
2. Use the "System backup" function in artifactory

So hopefully both backups are valid, after the backup is confirmed sent off site intact, I will be shutting down the artifactory server and wiping the artifacts from NFS. At some point in the future the data will be restored, the artifactory server itself will remain intact just powered off without artifacts.(unusual situation but that is the plan)

Anyway onto my issue, per [this document](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Importing+and+Exporting) I am attempting a full system level backup. However after a few minutes I get an strange error back and a stack trace in the logs, but the backup process seems to be continuing:

```
2022-10-10 19:24:35,451 [http-nio-8081-exec-10] [ERROR] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:790) - Job org.artifactory.repo.service.ExportJob cannot stop related job artifactory.ExportJob#bac2617d-9485-4bc9-a306-51ea5e038036 while it's
 running!
org.artifactory.schedule.TaskImpossibleToStartException: Job org.artifactory.repo.service.ExportJob cannot stop related job artifactory.ExportJob#bac2617d-9485-4bc9-a306-51ea5e038036 while it's running!
[..]
2022-10-10 19:24:35,452 [http-nio-8081-exec-10] [ERROR] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:791) - Full system export failed: Job org.artifactory.repo.service.ExportJob cannot stop related job artifactory.ExportJob#bac2617d-9485-4bc9-a306-51ea5e038036 while it's running!: Job org.artifactory.repo.service.ExportJob cannot stop related job artifactory.ExportJob#bac2617d-9485-4bc9-a306-51ea5e038036 while it's running!
2022-10-10 19:26:02,747 [art-exec-8] [INFO ] (o.a.r.d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93) - proddocker exported 3000 items (2907 files 93 folders 15.38 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2022-10-10 19:31:02,371 [art-exec-8] [INFO ] (o.a.r.d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93) - proddocker exported 6000 items (5823 files 177 folders 12.13 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
2022-10-10 19:35:22,406 [art-exec-8] [INFO ] (o.a.r.d.i.ImportExportAccumulator:93) - proddocker exported 9000 items (8743 files 257 folders 11.93 ips) 0 skipped items (0 files 0 folders)...
```

I came across [this document](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-monitor-the-system-import-and-export-processes/) which shows how to poll the running tasks. Checking the tasks the backup process is running. The repository is over 700GB so it will take a while. Perhaps this java stack trace is simply a minor bug with the UI trying to refresh or something?

After this happened the first time I restarted artifactory in case there was something else trying to run, I deleted all data in my destination backup directory so it was clean and started the system export again and the same error happened again.

Just hoping this backup isn't somehow corrupted as a result of this error. The backup was 130GB about 10-15mins ago and now up to 230GB, so it's still going..

thanks for any tips for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an export task had been previously started and was still undergoing when you triggered another export. Run the Get [Background Tasks REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetBackgroundTasks) to know if a background task is already running. This will tell us if indeed the system export hasn't finished. Perhaps the daily backup is running as well. A background task might have triggered a System Export before you triggered another one manually. You may need to check daily/weekly backup and their frequency. Mostly that is causing the issue.

The difference in your approaches.

1. Copy the raw repository data along with the MySQL DB
   I believe you are copying the binary data from filestore location (ideally $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore if you have not changed or your NFS drive)
   and taking the database backup. With this approach, you will be able to restore to the same state as of today in future.
2. Use the "System backup" function in artifactory
   You can later perform an import back to artifactory and your entire artifacts will be imported.

You can follow one of them. Also, you may want to visit [this article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/) that covers your usecases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I agree with your assessment of the difference in approaches. I verified there was no other backup running via the REST API. I even restarted Artifactory to clear anything that may of been running before. I aborted my backup just now(by restarting again) as I was assuming it was copying the artifacts pre-compressed seems it was not, backup was over 4TB when I aborted, will try again with compression on see how long that takes. Taking two backups I'm just trying to be ultra paranoid here.

Comment: This backup process is much less efficient than I expected. It seems it only compresses at the end, so it created another 3.5TB data export and is in the process of zipping it up, zip has been running for 4 hrs, looks like it might be halfway done based on the 350GB size. Though the backup job no longer shows in the REST API, java is still busy creating the archive(and the size is still increasing so the job is still active even though REST API says no jobs are running, all jobs show stopped or scheduled only).

Comment: Yes, the zipping will be done once the backup is completed and backuped folder will be deleted automatically and only the zip will be persisted.

Comment: One more update, I assume this is a real light zip compression, as there is only 769GB of data in the repository(I assume highly compressed), the backup tmp directory is 3.5TB, the zip file is 1.2TB and growing. Export has been running for 20 hrs so far.

Comment: Last update, I guess the original error I posted was safe to ignore(which is what I was hoping for). The log says full system export completed successfully. Total time was 33 hours for the export, and 2.3TB in size. I guess I will leave this post officially unanswered as I don't have a firm understanding of why the error occurred, only guesses as to what could of caused it(perhaps the browser re submitted the request again after not getting a response or something).